# Fast way to clear list or appropriate .NET collection for the following

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, collections

I have a need for a fast collection type which will only be accessed sequentially. It needs fast adds and fast clears. I would think there are some collection types that can be cleared with very little processing time.

I have read that `List<>` is O(n) operation. Is there a collection type with a super fast clear ability? Maybe a stack? Would a `List<int>` or `List<Double>` (non reference type) allow faster operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly need a fast clear and don't want to allocate a new piece of memory each time, you could also write your own implementation of `IList<T>` with a `Clear` that is O(1) by simply resetting the internal counter to 0. The `List<T>` class keeps a `_size` counter that determines where the list is at currently, to reset you could just set this to 0 in your own implementation. The internal array wouldn't really be cleared, but any items added to the list would override the old values and enumeration wouldn't continue past `_size` so you wouldn't ever touch the old values.

Essentially, you want `List<T>` where `Count` is settable to 0 rather than just gettable.

But do note that if `T` is a reference type, this kind of list would hold a reference to the old values and prevent them from being garbage collected. So perhaps only best used if you wanna store value types.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct answer because it shows there are 2 ways to solve this problem: Just create a new list or create an own implementation for value types.

Answer (score 4):

O(n) is when you are searching. If you are stepping through the list using the Enumerable (and maybe the indexer I don't know about that part) it will be O(1) lookups. <s>Clearing is O(1) too, as long as you are not doing `Remove(T obj)` calling `Clear()` will be very fast.</s> Clearing is still O(n).

If you don't need resizeablity just declaring an array will have a O(1) indexer and to "Clear" it you just dereference it and make a new one.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.100).aspx) clearing a list is O(N).

Comment: I thought it was as well, so I looked it up before writing an answer :) My guess would be due to the fact that the capacity will remain unchanged that it has to set all object references to `null`. I would assume under the hood there is probably so optimizations that make it more efficient than that, but worst case is O(N) since every element must be touched.

Comment: Clearing an existing list is O(N)... but you can always just create a new one instead.

Comment: I just love when people do "just create a new one instead" as if memory allocation is *free*. In a question which is obviously about performance.

Comment: @JBeurer it is a time/memory trade off. If you have the memory and the garbage collection does not affect the performance of your program in a relevant way, just allocating a new List is a perfectly fine operation.

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE for GC not to affect the performance of your program. Allocations in C# are only free up till the point GC collection hits, and as long as allocations are happening it will hit. The performance hit is just swept elsewhere, which paints the false picture of allocations "being free". Even Generation 0 collection will do mark&sweep - and that trashes cache. If the list<T> is large, the allocation will go straight up to Gen2/Large object heap, which will eventually trigger even more massive hit. This is obviously a performance focused question.

Comment: @JBeurer you still have to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), specifically 4th point eric makes, the simple solution may be plenty fast for his use case.

Comment: That's just sloppy engineering.
The simple solution is ONE "mov" instruction setting count variable to 0.
It can not get simpler (or faster) than that. 
Suggesting to make a memory allocation instead of single machine instruction, is just balls to the wall bananas. He specifically asked for quote "super fast clear ability"

Answer (score 2):

If you main goal O(1) for clear - just have any suitable collection (List, LinkedList, Array) as member of your cusomt class implementing `IList` or `ICollection` and forward indexing/iteration to that member. To implement clear simple create new instance of that inner member.

```
class FastClearList<T> : IList<T>
{
  List<T> inner = new List<T>();

  public void Clear()
  {
     inner = new List<T>(); // recreating list here will give O(1)
  }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
     return inner.GetEnumerator();
  }
  // forward everything else ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List does need to clear the references to objects that have been cleared. A best approach would be to create a new List<> instead of clearing it, or create a wrapper/factory that implements such an approach.